# How to write unit test to Restangular with Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, restangular

I know how to write test to GET methods, but what with other methods? PUT, PATCH, DELETE?

This is for example my service method to remove user:

```
removeOne: function(user) {
      var deferred;
      console.log(user);
      deferred = $q.defer();
      if (_.isUndefined(user.id) || _.isNaN(user.id)) {
        AlertsServ.logError(err);
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else {
        user.remove().then(function(result) {
          AlertsServ.logSuccess('Użytkownik został usunięty');
          return deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function(err) {
          AlertsServ.logError(err);
          console.log(err);
          return deferred.reject(err);
        });
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

It should be something like this:

```
describe('DELETE /users/1', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    return $httpBackend.expect('DELETE', BACKEND_URL + '/users/1').respond(200, 'user1');
  });
  return describe('removeOne method', function() {
    return it('should get one user', function() {
      var user;
      user = {
        id: 1,
        routes: 'users'
      };
      return UserServ.removeOne(user);
    });
  });
});
```

but how to define user?

P.S.: How to define in Jasmine/Karma Restangular base url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, with more experience in unit testing, I think that I should mock Restangular and test only if Reastangular are properly called with arguments. I shouldn't add $httpBackend in this tests.

In unit tests, I should check if my services working good, not external libraries. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

There is an useful example on [Restangular Github issue page](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/98#issuecomment-19091163).

If you would like to add `expect()` to check the response value, don't forget to understand `sanitizeRestangularOne()` or `sanitizeRestangularAll()` functions.